# How to detect changing of attributes in a class?

Tags: object, attributes, listener

here is my problem with a Java program: I have two classes (let's call them Ob1 and Ob2), both with an integer and other attributes. Ob2 has an attributs 'ob1', which is an instance of Ob1. Ob1 creates Ob2, giving itself as 'ob1'. I want that as the integer of Ob1 is equal to integer of Ob2, something happens. How can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Need to indicate what language this is for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: you cannot. Nothing in Java will notify anything else about a change in the value of a field.

Second answer: the integers in your class are private and only modified via 'set' functions, the set functions can make the check and make a call for you.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have alreay thought about an alternative way to do what I want, but would have like to do it with a kind of listener.